# Using another timestamp dataframe to filter a timestamp dataframe on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

My primary dataframe `df`

```
Id  timestamp
265 2017-05-22 02:57:29
267 2017-05-22 04:35:18
279 2017-05-22 11:08:14
281 2017-05-22 11:39:39
282 2017-05-22 11:40:42
285 2017-05-22 11:52:48
288 2017-05-22 12:00:29
```

My filter dataframe `df2`

```
Id  timestamp
283 2017-05-22 11:46:55
284 2017-05-22 11:51:41
286 2017-05-22 11:58:20
```

Normally I did

```
df[(df['timestamp'] >= '2017-05-22 11:46:55') & (df['dt'] =< '2017-05-22 11:58:20')]
```

But, this is not production friendly, and less reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) by `min` and `max` datetimes of `df2`:

```
df3 = df[df['timestamp'].between(df2['timestamp'].min(), df2['timestamp'].max())]
print (df3)
    Id           timestamp
5  285 2017-05-22 11:52:48
```

Comment: is between means (`>=` and `<=`)  or (`>` and `<`)

Comment: It is inclusive=True by default, so `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: But if add `inclucive=False` then get `>` and `<`

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Super, nice day!